# How can a BabylonJS FreeCamera be rotated from code?

Tags: 3d, browser-based-games

Say I have a FreeCamera in a BabylonJS 3D world. How could I rotate that camera from program code? Or, more specifically, how might I bind camera rotation (not movement, which I know how to bind to WASD) to the arrow keys so that gamers without a mouse would not find it too troublesome to use? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no pc gamers without a mouse, you can't even start the program easily without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeCamera extends TargetCamera, so it has a rotation variable. You can change this to rotate the camera around.